# Method to return multiple bits of text Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, dry, helper

I am currrently in the process of writing a new rails application and have a div near the top of my page called background that contains an image, a Title and some sub title text.

At the moment I have created seperate helper methods, as below, that passes in each of the elements by testing against the action and controller parameter.

This doesn't however seem like a very efficient way of implementing the code and so I was wondering what would be the best way to pass the three elements together in one method?

Currently I have a setup like this:

```
def background
    if params[:action] == "index" && params[:controller] == "everydays"
        return "/assets/everyday.jpg"
    elsif params[:action] == "index" && params[:controller] == "mens"
        return "/assets/mens.jpg"
    elsif params[:action] == "index" && params[:controller] == "womens"
        return "/assets/womens.jpg"
    end
end

def title_h1
    if params[:action] == "index" && params[:controller] == "everydays"
        return "Everyday"
    elsif params[:action] == "index" && params[:controller] == "mens"
        return "Mens"
    elsif params[:action] == "index" && params[:controller] == "womens"
        return "Womens"
    end
end


def title_h3
    if params[:action] == "index" && params[:controller] == "everyday"
        return "Example text for this Everyday Section"
    elsif params[:action] == "index" && params[:controller] == "mens"
        return "Example text for this Mens Section"
    elsif params[:action] == "index" && params[:controller] == "womens"
        return "Example text for this Womens Section"
    end
end
```

Any advice people can offer would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can return multiple values in single helper method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Debadatt. Do you know how I define where each part that is returned? For example how can I ensure the title_h1 text ends up in the correct div?

Comment: As you are fetching the values from helper methods by calling 3 methods. You can call single method from top of the div and capturing three values and replace those at their particular positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start working with hashes as it eliminates the many tests the if clauses are doing (so the following would all be helper methods):

```
def fragments
  return {
    "everydays#index" => {
      :background => "/assets/everyday.jpg", 
      :title => "Everyday",
      :description => "Example text for this Everyday Section"
    },
    "mens#index" => {
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
end

def fragment_for(segment)
  fragment = fragments["#{params[:controller]}##{params[:action]}"]
  fragment ? fragment[section] : nil
end
```

You can then put into your views:

```
<%= fragment_for :background %>
```

or

```
<%= fragment_for :title %>
```

etc.

BTW, plural of "man" is "men" and plural of "woman" is "women".

Answer (score 2):

You're right to be suspicious, that is a terrible code smell, and has surprisingly spilled over into the answers! I'll try to bring a little sanity to this page.

#### Use content blocks for your page-specific background image

```
# views/layouts/application

<% if content_for?(:background_image) %>
  <%= yield(:background_image) %>
<% else %>
  <img src="default" />
<% end %>

# views/everydays/index

<% content_for :background_image %>
  <img src="/assets/everyday.jpg" />
<% end %>
```

#### Use locale files for page-specific text

```
# locales/en.yml

everydays:
  index:
    title_h1: 'Everyday'
    title_h3: 'Example text for this Everyday Section'

# views/everydays/index

<h1><%= t('everydays.index.title_h1') %></h1>
```

If the `h1` tag is not within your `index` templates, as in, is a site-wide tag within your `application` template, then you can use code blocks as described above, or you could create a helper which fetches the relevant title based on the controller:

```
# application_helper.rb

def title(tag)
  t("#{params[:controller]}.#{params[:action]}.title_#{tag}")
end

# usage
<h1><%= title('h1') %></h1>
```

As you can see, there are many ways to approach this, and even improve on the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one return value in a method, like so:

```
def my_helper
  if action == 'something'
    return 'first return', 'second return', 'third return'
  else
    return 'first return 2', 'second return 2', 'third return 2'
  end
end
```

You can then call this method:

```
first_value, second_value, third_value = my_helper

<%= first_value %>
<%= second_value %>
<%= third_value %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a single method (say for ex : get_css_attribute_values) and return a hash where the key is name of the CSS attribute and the value is the string which you want to pass.

```
def get_css_attribute_values
  if params[:action] == 'index' && params[:controller] == 'everydays'
    return {:background_image => '/assets/everyday.jpg', :title_h1 => 'Everyday', :title_h3 => 'Example text for this Everyday Section' }
  elsif params[:action] == 'index' && params[:controller] == 'mens'
    return {:background_image => '/assets/mens.jpg', :title_h1 => 'Mens', :title_h3 => 'Example text for this Mens Section'}
  elsif params[:action] == 'index' && params[:controller] == 'womens'
    return {:background_image => '/assets/womens.jpg', :title_h1 => 'Womens', :title_h3 => 'Example text for this Womens Section'}
  end
end
```

Then you can access all these attributes in the view as :

```
get_css_attribute_values[:background_image]
get_css_attribute_values[:title_h1]
get_css_attribute_values[:title_h3]
```

Comment: Unless you store the return values on the first call this is no more efficient than the original question.

Comment: Yeah, I am not doing anything different. Just removed some duplication. :)